# configuring a newsgroup software to connect to a news/NNTP server thru TOR

Tags: configuration, windows

I'm configuring a newsgroup software to connect to a news/NNTP server thru TOR (tor-win32).

where do I put tor-win32 info within newsgroup software and where do I put
news/NNTP server within TOR

thank's in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If your newsgroup software allows for SOCKS5 proxy, then use localhost:9150. You must keep Tor Browser open at all times to provide connection to the Tor network.

If your software does not allow the use of a SOCKS5 proxy then it is not compatible and you may want to switch to another tool like Thunderbird which does allow it.